# Do TWAIN drivers benefit from multi-core CPUs?

Tags: performance, multi-core, multi-threaded, document-scanning, twain

Advanced TWAIN drivers of document scanners contain many image enhancement features such as descreen, color drop-out, despeckle, deskew, prevent see-through, etc. Some of these features are quite CPU intensive i.e. can slow down the scanning/image processing speed quite a bit.

Perhaps this is comparable to Photoshop or similar software where certain filters are quite CPU intensive as well. Photoshop, according to Intel, takes advantage of 4 or more processor threads of multi-core CPUs.

How about TWAIN drivers with CPU intensive image enhancement features? Are there such TWAIN drivers that are optimized for multi-core CPUs? If so, such drivers should process scanned images faster on multi-core CPUs as compared to single-core CPUs.

In case there are TWAIN drivers that use multi-core CPUs, which document scanner manufacturers offer them?

I ask this because I am looking into options to increase scanning speed.